# Xcode simulates App wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I don't know what I've done. Everything was working great until I started styling my app. So, I was working on my main storyboard and when I tried to simulate my App in the simulator. I saw my Icons flying around like crazy. 
I am more familiar with coding so I'm sorry if this is a nooby question but I don't know how to describe my problem to Google, I really tried it but it turns out to be other problems.

I will hang on screenshots, one is from my storyboard and the other one is whats the simulator shows me.

View in main storyboard:
[image: main storyboard]

View in simulator:
[image: simulator view]

Comment: You need to show - or at least explain - how you have your constraints set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and images, it looks like you're using auto layout but haven't applied enough constraints to locate the images where you want them, or the constraints are just wrong. Take a close look at your storyboard to make sure that you don't have any warnings about missing constraints, and that the constraints do what you want them to do.